# Download an object and save it as human-readable text-file

Tags: jakarta-ee, primefaces

I'am currently trying to allow users to fill out a form which represents an object and save it as a human-readable text-file. I'm using the primefaces fileDownload to achieve this.

My code works as far as that I can download the object as text-file and also upload it again with no problem. Unfortunately this is not human-readable.

While I'm creating a byte array in ASCII format, which is human-readable, converting it to "text/plain" makes it unreadable (which I find strange to begin with).

- How would I achieve what I need?
- Also, if possible, I need to edit the file a little before I finally save it (for example, I need to show the mail adresses contained in the dataObject as list -> 1 Mail per line)

JSF

```
 <p:commandButton value="#{resPage['button.export']}"
                  ajax="false" 
                  onclick="PrimeFaces.monitorDownload(start, stop);" 
                  icon="ui-icon-arrowthick-1-s"
                  title="#{resPage['button.export.tooltip']}">
                      <p:fileDownload value="#{distributionListEditor.export}" />
 </p:commandButton>
```

Java

```
/** 
 * Export the distribution list to a text file.
 */
public StreamedContent getExport() {

    String fileName= "Distribution_List.txt";
    DistributionListBean data = getObject();

    if(data == null) {

    data.setMembers(ItemUtil.convertFromItemList(recipients));
    data.setParameters(ItemUtil.convertFromItemList(parameters));

    try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
        oos.writeObject(data);
        oos.flush();
        oos.close();

        byte[] ascii = baos.toByteArray(); 

        InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(ascii);
        DefaultStreamedContent dsc = new DefaultStreamedContent(stream, "text/plain", fileName);

        return dsc;
    } catch(Exception ex) {
      LOGGER.error(ex);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: You seem to expect a 'serialized' object (cause that is what you effectively do) to be human readable. Try with static text first. If downloading that works, your issue is not primefaces related. Then fix your 'object- to-text' issue in a unit test

Comment: Agreed with @Kukeltje If you want it to be human readable you will have to "serialize" it in a readable format like XML or JSON.  You can use Google GSON for example.

Comment: You are completely right. I though this magic would somehow happen on it's own. I'll try converting it to GSON, JSON or XML first and post the corrected code, once it works. Thanks so far.

Comment: Why did you change the question like you did? Did you add the 'answer' in it?

Comment: I have added a reason for the edit. Seems this is only visible by clicking on "edited ... ago". Long story short, yes this is the answer. I will edit it again and do it right this time.

Comment: No, please create a real answer...below...you can see your edits by pressing the edited link (so they are not lost due to my 'rollback')

Comment: You're right, if I just update, people will see the answer but miss the question, so they benefit less from this topic. I hope I did it right this time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated my code, so that it now produces human-readable JSON. You need a JSON-viewer to read it though. Notepad++ works fine. If you use a "real" JSON-viewer, you will even have the lines formatted in an elegant way. 
Thanks @kukeltje for the correct answer and pointing out my edit-mistake. Thanks @melloware for suggesting "GSON", that made it quite easy.

JSF

```
 <p:commandButton value="#{resPage['button.export']}"
                  ajax="false" 
                  onclick="PrimeFaces.monitorDownload(start, stop);" 
                  icon="ui-icon-arrowthick-1-s"
                  title="#{resPage['button.export.tooltip']}">
                      <p:fileDownload value="#{distributionListEditor.export}" />
 </p:commandButton>
```

Java

```
/** 
 * Export the distribution list to a text file.
 */
public StreamedContent getExport() {

    String fileName= "Distribution_List.txt";
    DistributionListBean data = getObject();

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String dataString = gson.toJson(data);

    try {
        InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(dataString.getBytes());
        DefaultStreamedContent dsc = new DefaultStreamedContent(stream, "text/plain", fileName, "US-ASCII");

        return dsc;
    } 
    } catch(Exception ex) {
      LOGGER.error(ex);
    }
    return null;
}
```